# Typescript declarations for Firebase features not found

Tags: typescript, firebase, preact

I have a project set up with preact-cli and preact-cli-typescript-plugin. Everything compiles, runs, and works just fine, but I can't figure out how to import the typescript declarations for Firebase features. Here's an example of the issue.

```
import { CollectionReference, DocumentSnapshot, Firestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export default class FirestoreDatabase {
  private readonly itemCollection: CollectionReference;

  constructor(firestore: Firestore) {
    this.itemCollection = firestore.collection('items');
  }

  items(): Observable<DocumentSnapshot> {
    return Observable.create(observer =>
      this.itemCollection.onSnapshot(observer)
    );
  }
}
```

The class works just fine, and does what is expected, but I get a warning:

```
[ts] Could not find declaration file for module 'firebase/firestore'. '[project root]/node_modules/firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js' implicitly has type of any.
```

four times on that first line of code. All the typings for Firebase and it's feature modules are in node_modules/firebase/index.d.ts, but I'm not sure how to get the compiler to see that.

Answer (score 4):

I think I've figured this out. I shouldn't be importing CollectionReference, DocumentSnapshot, and Firestore. Instead I need to be using the fully qualified names of the types, `firebase.firestore.Firestore` for example. I can also use a type alias to make it shorter:

```
type Firestore = firebase.firestore.Firestore
type CollectionReference = firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
type QuerySnapshot = firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
```